# How to check if an object already called in Python?

Tags: python, object, pygtk, try-catch, instantiation

I created an GUI using PyGTK.

I want to add, in some cases, more UI elements to my GUI.
I did something like that:

```
try:
    self.main.addServer(self.factory.logingo)
except:
    self.main = MainWindow(self.factory.loginfo)
```

I want to call addServer when my object self.main (which is my gtk.Window object) already exist. But if it don't exist I want to call MainWindow which creates a gtk.Window.
My problem is, that my try never succeed and I always end in the except and recreate a self.main.

How to done that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
if not hasattr(self, 'main'):
    self.main = MainWindow(self.factory.loginfo)
self.main.addServer(self.factory.logingo)
```

PS: be ware of `try: ... except: ...` without any specific exceptation, unless when you know what are you doing. because that hides probable (and unexpected) exceptations. Instead, for example write:

```
try:
    ...
except AttributeError:
   ...
```

or anything that is expected and will be handled, instead of `AttributeError` (for example, `KeyError` or `IndexError` or `ImportError` or something)
And write as less code as possible in try block, for example you can write above code like this:

```
try:
    self.main
except AttributeError:
    self.main = MainWindow(self.factory.loginfo)
self.main.addServer(self.factory.logingo)
```

That is equivalent to that (its interesting to know that `hasattr` itself uses a try except!), But using hasattr is cleaner and shorter here.

Comment: I still get the same problem as in my first post. It always consider that self.main doesn't exist :-( So MainWindow is always called

Comment: So thats in your code's logic, and probably you should solve it yourself.